# How to increase height of image in R?

Tags: r, plot, size

I am using heatmap package and plotting heatmap from 400 rows and 10 column so plot looks very dense. Is there any way to plot png or jpeg image (as need to include in website) where length is 20 times than width. I tried to use

```
png("heatmap.png",width=10,height=200)
heatmap(some_data);
dev.off();
```

But height of png image gets changed not the plot size. how can i change plot size?

Comment: Are you using RStudio?

Comment: no i am running on linux terminal.

Comment: One workaround would be to use RStudio.  There's a window for plots in there, and if you click on 'export' it will let you adjust the width and height of your image based on pixels.